When parsing HTML using Beautiful Soup, children tags not there sometimes
Using Beautiful Soup, I am working on a pretty standard program that parses through HTML and retrieves data based on their CSS elements. The issue I am having is that when I retrieve the CSS tag in raw form, there are tags that exist that I cannot call.
Ive never ran into this before.
IMAGE
SEE IMAGE: The elements im looking for are the green items in BOTH the yellow and red tags, but am only getting the elements in the red box. Its almost as if the yellow box doesnt exist.
HTML here:
<div style="padding-left: 30px">
  <h3 class="section_title"><span class="toggler" id="REG_TAG_AUDIO_MESSAGE_GIA_CNFG">[-]</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal;">REG_TAG_AUDIO_MESSAGE_GIA_CNFG</span></h3><div class="canhide collapsable" style=""><div class="infoTable" style="padding-left: 30px">
  <table>
    <tbody><tr class="grayUnhidden"><th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Type</th><th>Type Description</th><th>Traceability</th><th>Config Note</th></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">queue_behavior</td><td>0x00000021 (IOP_AUD_BIT_PRIORITY_FIFO, IOP_AUD_BIT_INTERRUPT_NONE)</td><td>IOP_aud_queue_behavior_t32</td><td>audio queue behavior</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">gma_info.gma_model</td><td>IOP_AUD_CFG_GMA_36</td><td>IOP_audio_gma_model_t8</td><td>GMA model used in airframe</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">gma_info.gma_quantity</td><td>IOP_AUD_CFG_ONE_GMA_INSTALL</td><td>IOP_audio_gma_quantity_t8</td><td>number of GMAs used</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">gma_info.gma_audio_path</td><td>IOP_AUD_CFG_GMA_GIA6XW_DIGITAL</td><td>IOP_audio_gma_path_t8</td><td>GMA-GIA audio path type</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">gma_info.gma_path_fail</td><td>IOP_AUD_CFG_GMA_FAIL_CLASSIC_DIG_FAULT</td><td>IOP_audio_gma_path_fail_t8</td><td>audio path failure behavior</td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="padding-left: 30px">
    <h3 class="section_title"><span class="toggler">[-]</span><span>clip_volume[0]: IOP_AUD_DB_CLIP_DA40_ALERT</span></h3><div class="canhide collapsable" style=""><div class="infoTable" style="padding-left: 30px">
    <table>
      <tbody><tr class="grayUnhidden"><th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Type</th><th>Type Description</th><th>Traceability</th><th>Config Note</th></tr>
      <tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">database_clip_id</td><td>IOP_AUD_DB_CLIP_DA40_ALERT</td><td>IOP_audio_clip_t32</td><td>database clip id</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">attenuation</td><td>9</td><td>uint8</td><td>attenuation value</td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div><div style="padding-left: 30px">

When I run the following:
fifth_level = child.div.table.find_all('tr', class_='odd')
    for l in fifth_level:
        print(l)

Printing l gets me this:
<tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">database_clip_id</td><td>IOP_AUD_DB_CLIP_DA40_ALERT</td><td>IOP_audio_clip_t32</td><td>database clip id</td><td></td><td></td></tr>

<tr class="odd"><td style="width: 15%;">attenuation</td><td>9</td><td>uint8</td><td>attenuation value</td><td></td><td></td></tr>

To me, its clear that there are two distinct  elements, each with their own set of descendents. Where im having an issue, is I want the text from one of the  elements nested within. But when I call upon each  for the  using this code:
fifth_level = child.div.table.find_all('tr', class_='odd')
for l in fifth_level:
    # print(l)
    ltitle = l.td. text
    value = l.td.next_sibling.text
    print('TITLE:' + str(title) + '\t Name: ' + str(ltitle) + '\t VALUE: ' + str(value))

I get this result:
TITLE:clip_volume[0]: IOP_AUD_DB_CLIP_DA40_ALERT     Name: attenuation   VALUE: 9

When im expecting this result:
TITLE:clip_volume[0]: IOP_AUD_DB_CLIP_DA40_ALERT     Name: database_clip_id  VALUE: IOP_AUD_DB_CLIP_DA40_ALERT

TITLE:clip_volume[0]: IOP_AUD_DB_CLIP_DA40_ALERT     Name: attenuation   VALUE: 9

Referencing the attached image, why does l.td jump to the second <tr> tag. Whats even more interesting, is that when I call on the .contents or .children of l, the first <tr> and all of its descendents are nowhere to be found! Please help!

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

If you post the HTML as text we can copy and paste it to reproduce the problem.

I can't think of a reason why the first loop would show both rows, but the second one seems to skip the first row. Are you sure you're processing the same data in both cases?

This looks like an XY Problem. Please state clearly what your end goal is, as well as posting a minimal, reproducible example.

@Barmar Apologies. First post. Added full HTML as text. I absolutely am processing the same data in both cases, which is why this has been so perplexing to me

The behaviour described cannot be reproduced with the information provided; the question needs to be improved here, as already mentioned in the comments.
If the HTML exists in the specified form static in the soup and you only want to display the first two columns of each table including its preceding <h3> text, you could proceed like this starting from the <div>:
for l in soup.div.find_all('tr', class_='odd'):
    ltitle = l.td. text
    value = l.td.next_sibling.text
    print('TITLE:' + l.find_previous('h3').span.next_sibling.text + '\t Name: ' + str(ltitle) + '\t VALUE: ' + str(value))

To get the previous title, still reference the tree in this case:
l.find_previous('h3').span.next_sibling.text

To select only the second table adjust to:
for l in soup.div.find_all('table')[1].find_all('tr', class_='odd'):

